# Cannot access AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Getting an Error on this line

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

> Could not cast value of type 'LLAppDelegateProxy' (0x2bd218) to
>   'MyAppName.AppDelegate' (0x2bc708).

I was setting a RootViewController in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method which suddenly stopped working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just added LocalyticsBinding ? What else did you change ?

Comment: Yes, I have integrated Localytics. Is it because of Localytics?

Comment: did you google `LLAppDelegateProxy` ?

Comment: I did. Someone was suggesting to use the Localytics manual session integration.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible get access to the original `AppDelegate` using automatic integration. Add the following `static var` to your `AppDelegate` class:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static var originalAppDelegate:AppDelegate!
```

Next, set that variable at the beginning of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate = self
```

Now anytime you want access to your original `AppDelegate` you can retrieve it like so:

```
AppDelegate.originalAppDelegate.someMethod()
```